# Is there site for freelancers hiring freelancers?

Tags: freelance-websites

I'm again starting to try find freelancing jobs. Last time about 7 years ago, but unable to find work(with little work though), so my motivation dropped and I moved on.

I think that freelancing(expecially starting it) will require lot of work and it is art form as is.

I seen these work proposals, which has little or none information about eg.

"Need build website for business. 5 pages".

Well applying job and getting it is challenge. Then you have to convert client needs to actually what you need to do, Eg. hosting, dynamic or static website, database etc. When this task is done you can begin to work.

So, freelancers do above-mentioned task and then hire other freelancers to do these jobs.

Is this a thing and is there sites or services this kind of "work/job-flow".

Comment: Questions about Freelancing Website services for finding or working with clients are off topic. We are not the website's support channel, they have policies that dictate how they run, and they are typically better equipped to provide support. For more information, see the [help center](http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these sites are called "Freelancer websites".

To use those websites it doesn't matter if the client is also a freelancer.